# Error en envio de datos con prepare y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, prepared-statements

estoy intentando enviar informacion a mi base de datos despues de realizar dos consultas, la primera si el usuario ya existe y la segunda si el correo ya existe posteriormente realizo la "subida de informacion" a mi base de datos con mi sentencia preparada este es mi codigo:

```
             $loadtodatabase = $conn_reg->prepare("INSERT INTO usus (id, paterno ,materno ,nombre ,usuario ,pass ,email ,lvl ,telefono ,fecha ,code ,active ,profileimg)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
             $loadtodatabase->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $id, $paterno,  $materno,  $nombre,  $usuario,  $pass,  $email,  $lvl,  $telefono,  $joining_date,  $code,  $active,  $profileimg );

             $checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `paterno`, `materno`, `usuario`, `pass`, `email`, `lvl`, `telefono`, `fecha`, `code`, `active`, `profileimg` FROM `usus` WHERE `usuario` =  ?"); 
             $checkuser->bind_param("s", $nombre);
             $checkuser->execute();
             $checkuser->bind_result($id_d,$nombre_d,$paterno_d,$materno_d,$usuario_d,$pass_d,$email_d,$lvl_d,$telefono_d,$fecha_d,$code_d,$active_d,$profileimg_d);
            if ($checkuser->fetch()) {
                  if($usuario = $usuario_d) { 
                      echo "ya fue utilizado el nombre";


                  }else { 
                       $checkmail = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `paterno`, `materno`, `usuario`, `pass`, `email`, `lvl`, `telefono`, `fecha`, `code`, `active`, `profileimg` FROM `usus` WHERE `email` =  ?"); 
                       $checkmail->bind_param("s", $email);
                          $checkmail->execute();
                          $checkmail->bind_result($id_d,$nombre_d,$paterno_d,$materno_d,$usuario_d,$pass_d,$email_d,$lvl_d,$telefono_d,$fecha_d,$code_d,$active_d,$profileimg_d);
                          if ($checkmail->fetch()) {
                          if($email = $email_d) { 
                              echo "ya fue utilizado el correo";
                           }else {
                           if( $loadtodatabase->execute()){
                           echo "datos guardados"; 
                           }else {echo "error ";
                              }                            
                           }
                        }                                   
                     }
                  }
```

si utilizo usuarios ya registrados, si me da los errores, dependiendo si es un usuario ya ocupado o un correo electronico ya ocupado, pero al final de todo no guarda la informacion en la base de datos.

por si no se le entiende mucho al codigo lo explico rapidamente:

Se cargan las variables desde $_POST (esto no se ve en el codigo, no lo considere util)

Se realiza el prepared statement para escribir la informacion pero no se ejecuta.

se consulta si la variable $usuario existe en la base de datos (en caso de existir muestra el error en caso de no existir continua con un "else")

se consulta si la variable $email existe en la base de datos  (en caso de existir muestra el error en caso de no existir continua con un "else")

-------Aqui esta el problema----------
si $loadtodatabase logra ejecutarse muestra "datos guardados" (en caso contrario muestra error).

como puedo solucionar esa falla? las variables estan bien escritas y si hago "echo" para ver si tienen datos guardados los muestra.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar algo similar a esto:

```
$checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare("SELECT id FROM usus WHERE usuario = ?"); 
$checkuser->bind_param("s", $nombre);
$checkuser->execute();

$checkuser->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $checkuser->num_rows;

if($num_of_rows > 0){
    echo "ya fue utilizado el nombre";
}else{

    $checkMail = $conn_reg->prepare("SELECT id FROM usus WHERE email = ?"); 
    $checkMail->bind_param("s", $email);
    $checkMail->execute();

    $checkMail->store_result();
    $num_of_rows2 = $checkMail->num_rows;

    if($num_of_rows2 > 0){
        echo "ya fue utilizado el correo";
    }else{

        $insert_q = "INSERT INTO usus (id, paterno,materno ,nombre ,usuario ,pass ,email ,lvl ,telefono ,fecha ,code ,active ,profileimg)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
        $loadtodatabase = $conn_reg->prepare($insert_q);
        $loadtodatabase->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $id, $paterno,  $materno,  $nombre,  $usuario,  $pass,  $email,  $lvl,  $telefono,  $joining_date,  $code,  $active,  $profileimg);

        if($loadtodatabase->execute()){
            echo "INSERTADO!";
        }else{

            printf("Error: %s.\n", $loadtodatabase->error);
        }
    }
}
```

Yo particularmente utilizo PDO, espero poder ayudarte de todos modos.

Comment: lo cambiare en este momento pero como comentaba, si me detecta si hay un usuario y o email registrados, lo que no hace es completar el registro.

Comment: Entonces creo que lo que primero deberías verificar es si está correcta tu sentencia de insert, por ejemplo si es que no estás olvidando insertar algún dato obligatorio o quizás pueda ser el tipo de dato, según veo en el  bind_param todos son de tipo string. También podrías poner toda la parte del $loadtodatabase dentro del else ya que si no llega hasta ahí no se ejecutará eso

Comment: ya hice una correccion crucial y si me detecta si hay un correo o usuario repetido, pero como puedo hacer para recibir "debug" de cada paso en el envio del formulario?

Comment: Sigo con el gran problema, lo que logre hacer es identificar en donde exactamente esta el problema y son los siguientes:
la sentencia como me dijiste, y pues quite comillas y corregi sintaxis, Bind_param funciona (segun yo); ya que hice un IF para el execute pero no lo ejecuta

Comment: Lo primero es asegurarse que la sentencia funcina, te recomiendo que intentes ejectutar la sentencia en la bd directamente, si funciona intenta ejecutar $loadtodatabase. Una vez que funcione desde php agregale las validaciones (que solo se inserte si es que no hay nombres o email repetidos)

Answer (score 0):

Bien, lo resolvi! utilice `printf("Error: %s.\n", $loadtodatabase->error);` para ver que era lo que ocurria y me dio como resultado que $usuario ni $email podrian ser nulos (asi lo tengo en mi tabla), y acomode el script para que se ejecutara de manera mas ordenada asi

```
    $checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT `id`, `nombre`, 
    `paterno`,`materno`, `usuario`, `pass`, `email`, `lvl`, 
    `telefono`, `fecha`, 
    `code`, `active`, `profileimg` FROM `usus` WHERE `usuario` =  ?"); 
     $checkuser->bind_param("s", $usuario);
     $checkuser->execute();
     $checkuser->bind_result(
     $id_d,
     $nombre_d,
     $paterno_d,
     $materno_d,
     $usuario_d,
     $pass_d,
     $email_d,
     $lvl_d,
     $telefono_d,
     $fecha_d,
     $code_d,
     $active_d,
     $profileimg_d);
     if ($checkuser->fetch()) {}
     if($usuario = $usuario_d) {
           echo "ya esta registrado el usuario";
          $checkuser->close();}else { $ok1=1;$checkuser->close();}   
     $checkmail = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT `id`, `nombre`,
      `paterno`, `materno`, `usuario`, `pass`, `email`, 
     `lvl`,`telefono`, 
     `fecha`, `code`, `active`, `profileimg` FROM `usus` WHERE `email`
      =  ?"); 
     $checkmail->bind_param("s", $email);
     $checkmail->execute();
     $checkmail->bind_result(
     $id_d,
     $nombre_d,
     $paterno_d,
     $materno_d,
     $usuario_d,
     $pass_d,
     $email_d,
     $lvl_d,
     $telefono_d,
     $fecha_d,
     $code_d,
     $active_d,
     $profileimg_d);
     if ($checkmail->fetch()) {}
     if($email = $email_d) { 
             echo "ya existe el correo";
             $checkmail->close();                        
                 }else { $ok2=1;$checkmail->close();}

                if($ok1=1) {
                if($ok2=1) {
                      /*     IMPORTANTE!!!!!!
                        reasignamos los valores que
                        se perdieron en las consultas  */
                        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                        $email= $_POST['email'];            

                     $consulta=("INSERT INTO `usus` (id,nombre, paterno, materno, usuario, pass, email, lvl, telefono, fecha, code, active, profileimg)
                     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
                if($loadtodatabase = $conn_reg->prepare($consulta)) {
                   $loadtodatabase->bind_param("issssssssssss",$id, $nombre, $paterno,$materno,$usuario,$pass,$email,$lvl,$telefono,$joining_date,$code,$active,$profileimg);
                if($loadtodatabase->execute()){echo "Ejecutado con exito!";$loadtodatabase->close();
                printf("Error: %s.\n", $loadtodatabase->error);
                }else { echo "No ejecutado"; $loadtodatabase->close();
                printf("Error: %s.\n", $loadtodatabase->error);}
                }else {echo "error en preparacion de consulta<br>";
                $loadtodatabase->close();}
                }else {echo"<h1>check value 2 fail</h1>";$loadtodatabase->close();}
                }else {echo"<h1>check value 1 fail</h1>";$loadtodatabase->close();}
```